# Executing commands in php as root user in arch linux

Tags: php, apache, archlinux

i am using arch linux. i want to execute the php file which changes the ip of the system. i did

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.163.137
```

in the terminal and it works fine. the same i tried doing with

```
shell_exec('ifconfig eth0 192.168.163.137');
```

in a php file and tried opening the page from a remotely located web browser from another pc connected via router. teh page displays nothing and the code also doesnt execute. i guess its the problem with the user executing it.apache is executing it. so i want it to be run by the root.can anyone please guide me to the execution of my code. i even installed sudo and just put

```
shell_exec('sudo ifconfig......');
```

it too doesnt execute...please help...thanku..:)

Comment: A good way to debug is to echo the return value from the function. Always helpful. The function on its own doesn't write to the output buffer.

Comment: tried doin that...it doesnt return anything. only if config if done using shell_exec('ifconfig'); and the return value echoed then i am getting the complete text on the web page, the text is the text that gets displayed on the terminal

Comment: just tel me how to execute as a root..

Answer (score 3):

Sudo normally requires an interactive shell to enter your password. That's obviously not going to happen in a PHP script. If you're sure you know what you're doing and you've got your security issues covered, try allowing the Apache user to run sudo without a password, but only for certain commands.

For example, adding the following line in your sudoers file will allow Apache to run sudo without a password, only for the ifconfig command.

```
apache ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/ifconfig
```

Adjust the path and add any arguments to suit your needs.

**Caution:**

- There might still be complications due to the way PHP calls shell commands.
- Remember that it's very risky to allow the web server to run commands as root!

**Probably a better alternative:**

- Write a shell script with the suid bit to make it run as root no matter who calls it.

Comment: Expanded onto this. Have a bash script running as a cron job every minute or so. So when you want to change IP, your web server changes a text file, or insterts into database. The bash script checks this and does the ifconfig command. So your web server doesn't have root access.

Comment: setuid will not work on shell scripts. David's solution is better than sudo.

Comment: @strkol Dang, forgot that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**shell_exec**

> This function is disabled when PHP is running in safe mode.

Documentation : http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

So, maybe try tweaking your `php.ini` file?

Answer (score 0):

Write the commands to a queue and have cron pick them up, validate them (only allow known good requests), and run them, then mark that queue complete with the date and result.

Your end-user can then click/wait for update using ajax.